# How to create a bulge in an image in Python?Preferably using Pincushion Distortion

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to remove a bulge that I have in a test image that I have for a computer graphic project. The image has a fish eye kind of effect. I think it was created by using barrel effect I want to deflate that bulge and make the image normal.Well I read about barrel and pincushion effects in image processing.I think that it can be solved by using the negative radial distortion(Pincushion Effect) but how do you implement that in python and OpenCV

Can someone please put a solution here?
Ps. I tried to use Wand but it was of no great help

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please add the image in the question.

Comment: I've added the image , there was an edit to be made

Comment: You would need to know the radial distortion coefficients needed to remove it. ImageMagick has a barrel and inversebarrel command, if you are willing to use it. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#barrel. But I do not know how to tell you how to determine the coefficients you would need. I also do not support captcha breaking.